# Is there any method to get count of new added items to list adapter in android?

Tags: android, listadapter

Hie...every one.I want to show badge in my activity(containing list view )and the badge should contain the count of new list items added to that list view.Whenever i resume the activity the badge should refresh with updated count..does any have solution? Is there any methood from adapter to get new added items to that adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my knowledge there is only a method to get total items in adapter if you want to store elements count those are added newly then use **SharedPreferences**

whenever your adding new item to adapter then call

```
mSharedPreferences.putInt("count", mSharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0)+1);
```

If you want to display count just call

```
int count=mSharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: @Andro Leaven Good :-) Always support developer efforts.

Answer (score 0):

No, as fas as i know there is no method to count newly added items , method getCount() will always return you total items.

You have to make method inside adapter by your self like

```
public static int newItems=0;
```

update newItems when you adding items to your adapter

```
public int getNewAddedItemCount(){
return newItems;
}
```

Hope this will help you, if you understand what i trying to say.

Comment: Thanks to both of you..n yes Ishrat i m getting what u want to say

Comment: ya..i have the list items with date on which they are added to server(Database).Now ,when i am visiting to list Activity,OnResume() of that activity m storing the visit time(LastSeenTimeStamp) in shared preference and in another dbHandler class while adding  data from server to local DB (sqlite) m compairing list item time with LastSeenTimeStamp(sharedPreference) and updating the badge count(sharedPreference)..

Comment: Then you should accept or upvote helping answer which give you idea about this.

Comment: but i know it has some failure cases like u have to assume that when you Resume list activity all items from server are fetched to local DB and get added to adapter..but the failure probablity will be very low if u synch data properly